# Many-to-Many Association with Extra Columns

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, many-to-many, hibernate-mapping

I am not able to map correctly even following all the steps provided in:
https://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-many-to-many-example-join-table-extra-column-annotation/

```
CREATE TABLE `tb_pla_playlist` (
`id_playlist` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`nm_playlist` VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id_playlist`) USING BTREE,
)
CREATE TABLE `tb_mid_midia` (
`id_midia` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`nm_midia` VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id_midia`) USING BTREE
)
CREATE TABLE  `tb_mip_midia_playlist` (
`id_midia` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
`id_playlist` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
`nr_ordem` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
`CREATED_BY` VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id_midia`,`CATEGORY_ID`),
CONSTRAINT `FK_id_midia` FOREIGN KEY (`id_midia`)
         REFERENCES `midia` (`id_midia`),
CONSTRAINT `FK_id_playlist` FOREIGN KEY (`id_playlist`)
         REFERENCES `playlist` (`id_playlist`)
)
```

playlist.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name="tb_pla_playlist")
public class Playlist implements Serializable {
private Set<MidiaPlaylist> midiaPlaylist = new HashSet<MidiaPlaylist>(); 

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name="id_playlist")
private Long idPlaylist;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "id.playlist", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private Set<MidiaPlaylist> getMidiaPlaylist(){
    return midiaPlaylist;
}
...
}
```

[erro: In attribute 'midiaPlaylist', the "mapped by" value 'id.playlist' cannot be resolved to an attribute on the target entity.]

midia.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name="tb_mid_midia")
public class Midia implements Serializable {
private Set<MidiaPlaylist> midiaPlaylist = new HashSet<MidiaPlaylist>(); 

@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column(name="id_midia")
private Long idMidia;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "id.midia", cascade=CascadeType.ALL)  
public Set<MidiaPlaylist> getMidiasPlaylist() {
    return midiaPlaylist;
}
```

[erro: In attribute 'midiasPlaylist', the "mapped by" value 'id.midia' cannot be resolved to an attribute on the target entity.]

MidiaPlaylistPK.java

```
@Embeddable
public class MidiaPlaylistPK implements Serializable {
    private Midia midia;
private Playlist playlist;

@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
public Midia getMidia(){
    return midia;
}
public void setMidia(Midia midia){
    this.midia = midia;
}

@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
public Playlist getPlaylist(){
    return playlist;
}

public void setPlaylist(Playlist playlist){
    this.playlist = playlist;
}
}
```

MidiaPlaylist.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name="tb_mip_midia_playlist")
@AssociationOverrides({
   @AssociationOverride(name="id.playlist", [erro: Persistent type of override attribute "id.playlist" cannot be resolved]
   joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "id_playlist")),
   @AssociationOverride(name="id.midia", [erro: Persistent type of override attribute "id.midia" cannot be resolved]
   joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "id_midia"))
   })
 public class MidiaPlaylist implements Serializable {   
 private MidiaPlaylistPK id = new MidiaPlaylistPK();
 private int nrOrdem;

 @EmbeddedId    [erro: Embedded ID class should not contain relationship mappings]
 public MidiaPlaylistPK getId() {
    return this.id;
 }
@Column(name="nr_ordem", nullable=false)
public int getNrOrdem(){
    return this.nrOrdem;
}

@Transient
public Midia getMidia(){
    return getId().getMidia();
}

@Transient
public Playlist getPlaylist(){
    return getId().getPlaylist();
}
```

[Relational model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/85o4B.jpg)

Can someone help me with these errors? Ty!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should remove `@ManyToOne` anotation in `@Embeddable` and use `@MapId` anotation insted of `@Transient`, there is an example here:
http://www.objectdb.com/api/java/jpa/MapsId

Comment: I have very little experience in mapping. And I do not understand why these mistakes. I need to create a ManyToMany relationship between media and playlist. Is there any easy way to do this? Searching on MapId, apparently it does a ManyToOne mapping and in the case I need ManyToMany with extra columns. [link](http://www.thejavageek.com/2014/09/26/jpa-mapsid-example/)

Comment: Thank you for helping me. Would that be the solution?
 ´
        `@MapsId("midia")
 public Long getMidia(){
  return getId().getIdMidia();
 }
 
 @MapsId("playlist")
 public Long getPlaylist(){
  return getId().getIdPlaylist();
 }
 
 @ManyToOne Midia midia;
 
 @ManyToOne Playlist playlist; 
 

 @Column(name="nr_ordem", nullable=false)
 public int getNrOrdem(){
  return this.nrOrdem;
 } `

Comment: In current example yes, it's for ManyToOne mapping(it's only show how to use MapsId anotation), but in your case you will have two MapsId and you will get what you want.

Comment: No, you should have only  id values `MidiaPlaylistPK`(not entities), and entities with mapings and MapsIds in `MidiaPlaylist`.